# Spring, JSF, How to send events between beans from two different sessions

Tags: spring

I want to send event or message between beans from different session instances.

*Service which send events:*

```
@Service
@Scope("singleton")
public class ServiceA
{
   void methodA()
   {      
      ...
      messanger.post(new ReloadColorsEvent());  
   }
}
```

*Bean which handles event:*

```
 @Bean
 @Scope("session")
 public class EventHandler() 
 {
    @PostContruct
    void registerEvents()
    {
      messanger.register(this);
    }   

    void handleFun(ReloadColorEvent reloadColorEvent)
    {   ... 
    }
 }
```

Let's say that we have 2 logged users. So, 2 sessions were created (*session 1* and *session 2*). Session 1 and Session 2 have own `EventHandlers`.
After `methodA` is called event is send.

Now, I want to handle this event by `handleFun` method in `EventHandler` object from session1 and session2.

Answer (score 1):

There is noting special about it - since you registered your `EventHandler`s with `messanger`, you can make it send events to them. And since you use `this` to register `EventHandler` there should be no interference with scoped proxies (if you use them).

However, note the followng:

- Don't forget to unregister `EventHandler` when session is destroyed (for example, in `@PreDestroy` method)
- Take care of thread safety
- You'll have problems if your `EventHandler` references other `session`-scoped beans that use scoped proxies and you use them inside `handleFun()`. Since `handleFun()` is executed outside of session context, `session`-scoped beans behind proxies won't be available

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But I`am not sure that I understood you last indicates. I have tried to write simple appllication according to your hints, and I have strange problem. Maybe it is exactly what you wrote in last advice. In handle fun I added "FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().get("myExistingBean")) and it isn`t working. Can it be somehow conntected with your third advice ?

Comment: @Lehu: Yes, I think it's the same point. Since you call `handleFun()` inside the scope of different request (associated with the different session), all features that rely on request-specific or session-specific contextual information will work with the context of that request. So, `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` returns `FacesContext` for the actual incoming request.